# Find equation of the curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The product of the slope of the tangent  line to a curve and sum of the coordinates of the point of contact equal  to the ordinate for any point of the curve. This curve pass through the point $M_0 (2,0).$ Find equation of the curve.

Write the  differential equation of the curve $$y'(x+y)=y.$$ Change of variables $z=\frac yx, \, y=zx, \, y'=z'x+z$

$$(z'x+z)(x+zx)=zx$$
$$z'x+z=\frac{z}{1+z}$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}x=\frac{-z^2}{1+z}$$
$$(\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z})dz=-\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\int(\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z})dz=-\int\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$-\frac{1}{z}+\ln |z|=-\ln|x|-\ln|C|$$
$$\frac{1}{z}=\ln Cxz$$
$$\frac{x}{y}=\ln Cy$$
$$x=y \ln Cy$$
$$e^x= (Cy)^y$$
if this curve pass through the point $M_0 (2,0)$  then $$e^2=(C\cdot 0)^0$$

But this is absurd!
What did i do wrong?
I am sorry for my English.

Comment: How did you get from $x=y\ln(Cy)$ to the (wrong) exponentiated form? Getting $e^x=(Cy)^y$ would have been OK, but not necessarily useful.

Comment: We do not have $e^{st}=e^se^t$. But my remark, though correct, is not relevant, since there is trouble anyway because $y=0$.

Comment: yeah, so the first problem is that it should $e^{\frac{x}{y}} = Cy$, but the problem as y = 0 persists. You have an initial condition which fails our argument. I think you should modify your question to ask for a solution, as we now know the problem in your argument.

Comment: @André Nicolas Oops I fixed it.  Maybe problem  defined incorrectly. But this problem is in  homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You cannot solve it using standard solution to a first order linear differential equation, since the initial condition gives you an absurd answer.
- Fit the initial condition in the equation itself to see that $y'$ must be $0$ at $M_0$
- A bit of guess-work leads you to the function $y = 0$ which satisfies the condition given in the problem.
- The standard solution doesn't work since $z = 0$ throughout the integration on LHS while x not so much.

**Solution :** $y = 0$